# Bug in "Upcoming Reputation History Changes"

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)

After migration to the [new reputation history system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), it seems I lost (user: 0x69) a bucket of reputation because now SO tells that some questions are missing:

```
-128     22:34  deleted "My boss asks me to pirate software. What should I do?"
-250     23:57  deleted "Learning to Write a Compiler"
```

How is that? These questions are now not part of SO because of the rep system migration?
Or did the original posters delete these questions? Or something else?

Comment: Those questions were deleted, so all the rep you gained from it was removed.

Comment: Don't be sad, there were many people who lost way more rep than you on those questions.

Comment: Hm. I'm reluctant to close as the suggested dupe, because it's linked to in the question and therefore the OP obviously already saw it. On the other hand, it does explain exactly what happened.

Comment: "My boss asks me to pirate software. What should I do?" - now that really piqued my interest but no chance to see it anymore

Comment: @prusswan - You are lucky :-), here is a copy from [google webcache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_4LyxpxXCHMJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/3907076/my-boss-asks-me-to-pirate-software-what-should-i-do+My+boss+asks+me+to+pirate+software.+What+should+I+do%3F&cd=1&hl=lt&ct=clnk&gl=lt)

Comment: Or if you want more cleaner page look, but it is ok to have a little bit older snapshot - then you can check in [webarchive](http://web.archive.org/web/20101015013349/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907076/my-boss-asks-me-to-pirate-software-what-should-i-do) - another good snapshot service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those questions were deleted, so the reputation was removed.  The *previous* bug was that the effect of that deletion was not immediate, it didn't happen until a reputation recalc was performed (which happened last night, which is why it *just now* took effect).

Going forward, your reputation will be updated within 5 minutes of the deletion.

Comment: Within 5 minutes? Does that also apply to reputation restored from downvotes? If so might that not make it possible to confirm suspicions of who downvoted an answer by deleting the answer and then checking the suspect(s)' reputation for an unaccounted for +1 a few minutes later?